# Could someone explain this proof to me?

Tags: calculus

I found [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-101-analysis-ii-fall-2005/lecture-notes/lecture3.pdf) from MIT OCW.

Please scroll down to **Theorem 2.4**:

*If f is differentiable at a, then for every u the directional derivative of f in the direction of u at a exists*

Could someone explain $(2.17)$? How did that go to $0$? And I don't see how $2.18$ follows from that? Did they multiply and divide t in $2.17$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(2.17)$ is another way of writing the expression in $(2.16)$, which goes to $0$ as $t \rightarrow 0$.

Then you have the product of two things going to $0$ as $t \rightarrow 0$, where one of the things is $\frac{t}{|t|} \frac{1}{|u|}$ and the other is the stuff in parentheses.

Note that the first thing does not approach $0$ as $t \rightarrow 0$, so it must be the parenthetical stuff going to $0$.

Since the parenthetical thing is of the form $X - Y$, this means that $X - Y \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow 0$, i.e., $X = Y$ as $t \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: How do they know the thing $X - Y$ goes to $0$? That's not obvious at all, especially with the $\mathbb{u}$ in there

Comment: if $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \alpha(t) \cdot \beta(t) = 0$, then either $\alpha = 0$ or $\beta = 0$ or both as $t \rightarrow 0$. In this case, you have the product of two things, where one of them is not going to $0$ as $t \rightarrow 0$. Thus, it must be the other one that goes to $0$.

Comment: Sorry, I am asking why does (individually, as a limit) $X - Y$ go to $0$?. I want to know why $\alpha \to 0$

Comment: $(2.16)$ gives you an expression of the form $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \gamma(t) = 0$. Next, the author rewrites $\gamma(t) = \alpha(t) \cdot \beta(t)$, so that this latter expression will also go to $0$ as $t$ does. Since $\alpha(t)$ does not go to $0$, it must be that $\beta(t) = X - Y \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow 0$, i.e., $X = Y$ as $t \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Okay sorry, I meant to say why does $\beta (t)$ go to $0$. There is a miscommunication. Let's just forget the last step is even there, that is "$\to 0$". I want to know where does $X - Y \to 0$. I know the process of elimination here